# Isoperimetric type inequality in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Fix $L \in (0,\infty)$ and consider $\mathcal{C}_L$ defined as follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}_L := \{ \gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 |~ \gamma \text{ is smooth and length($\gamma$)$=L$ }\}. 
\end{align*}

I am interested in the "blow-up" of $\gamma$, denoted $\gamma_{+r}$, defined as follows: For any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and $r>0$
\begin{align*}
S_{+r} := \cup_{z\in S}(z+r\mathbb{D}),
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is centred at the origin. So $\gamma_{+r}$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. My question is for which $\gamma \in \mathcal{C}_L$ is $m(\gamma_{+r})$ maximised? Here $m(\cdot)$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I feel that it should be maximised by the line segment with length $L$.

If this is a version of some well known result, please do indicate it.

The reason for this title is that sometimes the isoperimetric inequality in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is stated as follows: For any Borel subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with $m(A) < \infty$ and  for every $\epsilon >0$, we have $m(A_{+\epsilon}) \geq m(B_{+\epsilon})$. Here $B$ is a Euclidean ball with $m(A) = m(B)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is maximised by any twice-differentiable curve for which the radius of curvature is greater than or equal to $r$. This follows from the Weyl formula for the volume of tubes, especially the original 1939 paper by Hotelling on the subject, "Tubes and Spheres in n-Spaces, and a Class of Statistical Problems".